# htaccess include query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know similar questions have been asked a lot of times, but mine is a bit different.

This is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^activate$ activate.php
```

When the user requests `/activate?q=foo` I want the user redirected to `/activate.php?q=foo`
Currently it just truncates the query string and redirects the user to `/activate.php`.

Now, I've tried the `[QSA]` flag, but it seems to force a 301 redirect, which is not an option in this case.

I've also tried the stuff with `$1` and so on but I simply couldn't get it to work.

I did a Google Search before asking this question. I went to page 10 on Google on `htaccess include query string` before I decided to ask here.

And just to repeat, a 301 redirect is not an option, it has to stay on the same page, but load the other one (I think it's called an internal redirect, I'm not sure though).

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT:**

[As Mike S. requested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/34289169?noredirect=1), here is my full htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^feedback$ feedback.php
RewriteRule ^roomie$ roomie.php
RewriteRule ^nyroomie$ addroomie.php
RewriteRule ^registrer$ register.php
RewriteRule ^activate$ activate.php

AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile *CENSORED*/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Comment: There is no reason, why RewriteRule should use 301 to achieve this. QSA should be enough. Can you show more of your .htaccess?

Comment: Try to use [R,L] at line with redirect to HTTPs and on every line with basic RewriteRule [L,QSA], then it should be working...

Comment: L,R @ line line with HTTPS, on any other, use L,QSA

Comment: I updated it to look like this:
`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]`
`RewriteRule ^activate$ activate.php [L,QSA]`

It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely happening due to enabling of option `MultiViews` (Content Negotiation) which conflicts with `mod_rewrite`. Add this line on top to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Adding that made the server return a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Which means you don't have access to change `Options` in .htaccess. In that case you need to get that added in server config by your admin.

Comment: I'm on a shared server. My host doesn't give me access to that, sorry. Do you know of any other solution, this surely can't be impossible.

Comment: It is very much possible and I have provided my answer. Many people use shared servers these days but still get work done by server admins when needed.

Comment: Well my host in particular doesn't give me access to this. I just asked them. What I meant by "impossible" was possible without this function. I don't see why I'd need to use Options.